# How do I grep to remove entries that start with a "chr1" but keep those with "chr11" or "chr19"?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have a file with entries like this:

```
chr1    740678  740720
chr1    2917480 2917507
```

I want to remove the entries which start with `chr1` but retain others which start with `chr11` or `chr19` and so on. When I use `grep -v "chr1"` it removes the others which start with chr11 or chr19.
Can I use another regular expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you should anchor your regular expression to only match at the beginning of the line (`^chr1`) to avoid finding lines that contain `chr1` but it isn't the first string (this can easily happen with an annotated VCF file, for example). Next, you can use the `-w` option for (GNU) `grep`:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing matches that
          form whole words.  The test is  that  the  matching
          substring  must  either  be at the beginning of the
          line,  or  preceded  by  a   non-word   constituent
          character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end
          of the line or followed by a  non-word  constituent
          character.     Word-constituent    characters   are
          letters, digits, and the underscore.   This  option
          has no effect if -x is also specified.
```

If your `grep` doesn't support that, then use this:

```
grep -v '^chr1\s' file
```

The `\s` matches whitespace (including both tabs and spaces), so that will exclude any lines that start with `chr1` and then any kind of whitespace character.

Comment: I wonder if `\b` (word boundary) would work in this context - and might be more portable than `\s`?

Comment: @steeldriver hmm, yes (by the way, wouldn't `\>` be more portable? I thought `\b` was an ERE or even PCRE thing) but that would also exclude things like `chr1|chr2`, for example, which might be a problem for the OP.

Comment: I get so confused! I *thought* that `\b` was the POSIX one and that `\>` and `\<` were GNU-specific. Also that `\s` is really from PCRE (although apparently supported by GNU grep in both ERE and BRE mode)

Comment: @steeldriver ugh, I don't know either. I admit I tend to stick to PCRE whenever remotely possible and never remember the details for this sort of edge case. According to [this](https://regular-expressions.mobi/wordboundaries.html?wlr=1) you're absolutely right and `\>` and `\<` are GNU extensions. However, according to that, so is `\b` so go figure :). And yes, I only found out that GNU `grep` supports `\s` when I read [nobody's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602958/). I'd always assumed it didn't since the `\s` is a PCRE thing and just used `grep -P`.

Comment: If your looking for portability maybe `[[:space:]]`?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there are some spaces or tabs after chr1. So you could search for `chr1`, which is followed by some whitespace characters. Try this:

```
grep -v "chr1\s\+"
```

Comment: The \+ could be unnecessary.

Comment: @pasaba por aqui: You are right.